Theorem Guaranteeing Collapse Into Black hole?
Is there any mathematical theorem that shows -- compatible with the kind of assumptions about quantum effects needed for Hawking radiation -- that sufficiently dense and massive objects under the right conditions necessarily collapse into a black hole?  Not just get very close to one but actually satisfy the conditions of the Penrose singularity theorem?
This is probably a question with a really obvious answer to a physicist but whenever I ask my physicist friends about this I only get heuristic arguments.  As a mathematician that makes me feel queasy when infinities are involved.  I mean without a theorem why would you be confident that evaporation like effects don't allow for a solution where the manifold just gets really really close to having a singularity?
I mean how can the AdS/CFT correspondence accommodate the change in the topology in one description when the singularity forms?

Something is a black hole if it has an event horizon, not if it has a singularity...

@MitchellPorter An evaporating "black hole" does not have an event horizon. The event horizon is defined as the region with no escape ever. However after the full evaporation no such region exists and therefore it has never existed.

Both the question and the current answer suffer from the same popular misconception that quantum effects become critical only near the singularity thus potentially preventing the singularity from forming. However the quantum effects become critical already at the horizon preventing a trapped surface from forming, causing the Information Paradox, breaking the classical theory at the horizon and thus preventing the formation of the singular region inside the "black hole" in the first place. Classically this singular region exists "after" the cosmological eternity, but QM eliminates this absurd.

@safesphere The question was exactly why should one think that quantum effects don't prevent the formation of the black hole.  The reason I said evaporation like effects rather than evaporation was exactly to try and finesse this concern but indicate I didn't want "we can't prove this bc no complete quantum theory" but an answer like "if we assume ... which seems to be satisfied in the kind of QM approximation we use to derive evaporation results ... then a bh must form"

@PeterGerdes One issue here is the definition of BH. A star collapses fast to what cannot be distinguished from a BH and exists for a gazillion years. And then it vanishes into the radiation meaning that it has never been a true BH. If you insist it wasn't a BH, then BHs don't exist and we should use a different term like "collapsars". Or else we can just keep calling them BHs and drop the Penrose Singularity Theorem from the definition as unrelated to physical reality. Either way the difference is only in the name, but if your question is based on this theorem then no BHs ever form.

@safesphere Yes, that ambiguity in what is meant when someone talks about blackholes existing is what bugged me to write the question in the first place.  All the time I see physicists (not just popularizers but people writing journal articles about the bh information problem) take it for granted that bh requires a trapped surface.  But all the arguments that bh exist (esp by astronomers) elide the distinction you mentioned.  And it's just conceptually wrong to confuse the two so why try to explain these concepts at all if it doesn't matter if you get them right
